# Does the Brute fighter's extra damage die get added to the monk's Martial Arts and Flurry of Blows attacks?

Tags: dnd-5e, monk, damage, fighter, unearthed-arcana

I am considering a build that would start with monk, then multiclass to fighter up to level 3 to get the [Brute](https://www.dndbeyond.com/characters/classes/fighter#Brute) archetype (from [Unearthed Arcana: Three Subclasses](https://media.wizards.com/2018/dnd/downloads/UA-3Subclasses0108.pdf)).

Would the extra damage die from the Brute subclass still get added to the monk's Martial Arts and Flurry of Blows attacks?

Comment: Where is this fighter subclass from? UA?

Comment: @Szega [Yes](https://www.dndbeyond.com/characters/classes/fighter#Brute)

Comment: Please note that [Unearthed Arcana is not tuned for Multiclassing](https://twitter.com/jeremyecrawford/status/791048635815301120).

Comment: in a home campaign I can multiclass with unearthed arcana features if I wish or am I wrong?

Comment: @Eternallord66 You definitely can. NautArch was just advising that it may not be perfectly balanced as Unearthed Arcana is playtest material and still undergoing changes.

Comment: @David Coffron Thank you for clarification.

Comment: Yes, my apologies if that came off as a You Can Not Do This At All :) But did want to let it be known that there may be unknown interactions that can make multiclassing with UA problematic at times.

Comment: Well, to be precise, whether UA is allowed, whether multiclassing is allowed, and whether you are allowed to use UA stuff with a character *and* multiclass that character (e.g. multiclassing with the UA revised ranger) are all up to the DM. But yeah.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Not with unarmed strikes

As of the [first Player's Handbook errata](https://media.wizards.com/2015/downloads/dnd/Errata_PH.pdf) unarmed strikes no longer count as weapons.

> Instead of using a weapon to make a melee weapon attack, you can use an un-armed [sic] strike: a punch, kick, head-butt, or similar forceful blow (none of which count as weapons).

The Brute Damage requires a weapon:

> Whenever  you hit with    a   weapon  that    you’re  proficient  with and    deal    damage, the weapon's damage increases

This means that Flurry of Blows can not use Brute Damage as it only uses unarmed strikes (**emphasis** mine):

> Immediately after you take the Attack action on your turn, you can spend 1 ki point to **make two unarmed strikes** as a bonus action.

### You could use a Monk Weapon with Martial Arts

Martial Arts affects certain weapons in addition to unarmed strikes (**emphasis** mine):

> - You can use Dexterity instead of Strength for the attack and damage rolls of your unarmed strikes **and monk weapons.**
> - You can roll a d4 in place of the normal damage of your unarmed strike **or monk weapon.**

If using a monk weapon, the Brute Damage would apply.

Comment: Since the question specifically calls it out, you should mention that "Flurry of Blows" does NOT use monk weapons, only unarmed strikes so those would not stack. "Immediately after you take the Attack action on your turn, you can spend 1 ki point to make **two unarmed strikes** as a bonus action."

Answer (score 5):

## The Brute's Damage is not added to unarmed strikes

The [Brute](https://www.dndbeyond.com/characters/classes/fighter#Brute) archetype says:

> #### Brute Force
>
> Starting at 3rd level, you’re able to strike with your weapons with especially brutal force. **Whenever you hit with a weapon** that you’re proficient with and deal damage, the weapon’s damage increases by an amount based on your level in this class, as shown on the Brute Bonus Damage table.

[Even though unarmed strike is considered a weapon attack, it is not considered a weapon](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/58158/35259), so the extra damage from Brute Force would not be added to it as it specifically says "hit with a weapon" rather than "make a melee weapon attack" like most features do, although it would of course still be added to any weapon attacks you make with a weapon.