# Can you use Thunderous Smite and other "Smite" spells with unarmed strikes?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, paladin, spell-components, unarmed-combat

Since unarmed strikes are considered melee weapon attacks, and the '*smite*' spells don't have the same restriction as *booming blade* or *green-flame blade* (the part where it requires "a weapon" as the material component).

Would you be able to cast and trigger the 'smite' spells (like *thunderous smite, searing smite*, etc.) with unarmed strikes as they are melee weapon attacks?

Comment: Related on [Is an unarmed strike considered a weapon attack?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/58158/is-an-unarmed-strike-considered-a-weapon-attack)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

## You need a weapon for all the smite spells (except *wrathful smite*)

#### Smite spells require a weapon

*Thunderous smite* says:

> The first time you hit with a melee weapon attack during the  spell's duration, **your weapon** rings with thunder ...

In fact, every smite spell has similar language specifically calling out the need for a weapon (except for *wrathful smite* see below). By a strict RAW reading though the weapon does not actually need to be the one that makes the attack, but you still need a weapon.

Regardless, I think it is pretty clear here that the spell is intended to utilize the weapon that you use to make the melee weapon attack even if the wording leaves a bit of a loophole. Either way, the spells do require a weapon.

#### The body/unarmed strikes are not weapons

The PHB says:

> Instead of using a weapon to make a melee weapon attack, you can use an unarmed strike: a punch, kick, head-butt, or similar forceful blow (**none of which count as weapons**). (PHB 195)

Suggesting that though body parts are not weapons, the unarmed strike still counts as a melee weapon attack but explicitly not a weapon.

And the [Sage Advice Compendium](https://media.wizards.com/2019/dnd/downloads/SA-Compendium.pdf) clarifies this and makes it explicit:

> [A]n unarmed strike counts as a melee weapon attack, even though **the attacker’s body isn’t considered a weapon**.

Since the smite spells specifically call out a weapon in their description, that is what they require. And since unarmed strikes are not considered to be weapons, then they do not qualify.

#### *Wrathful smite* does not need a weapon

*Wrathful smite* is, for some reason, the only smite spell that does not specifically call out the need for a weapon.<sup>1</sup>

> The first time you hit with a melee weapon attack during the  spell's duration, **your attack** deals an extra 1d6 psychic damage.

Thus, since the unarmed strikes do count as melee weapon attacks, a character would be able to use an unarmed strike to cause the effect, no weapon required at all.

---

<sup>1 - Thanks @Someone_Evil for catching this.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

I agree with [Rubiksmoose's answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/146759/do-you-need-a-weapon-for-thunderous-smite-and-the-other-smite-spells/146761#146761) that the *smite* spells (except *wrathful smite*) require a weapon.

However, I thought it might be useful to share my own house ruling on the subject. I decreed that, while the resident paladin couldn't use a smite barehanded, a **gauntlet** could count as a weapon for the purposes of the various *smite* spells.

Note that, to the best of my knowledge, gauntlets arent considered weapons anywhere in the RAW.  They do, however, provide a way to "disarm" a paladin so that they can't just punch holes through monsters with impunity. I felt it wouldn't break the game too much to tweak the rules in such a fashion, and I honestly wanted to see where she was going with it.

The paladin eventually took advantage of this ruling to literally backhand a wereboar to death.  It was a very cool moment in-game, and I regret nothing.  As always, Your Mileage May Vary.