# Are the Gray and Death Slaad's Bite and Claw attacks magical?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, attack

The Gray and Death Slaadi from the *Monster Manual* have the **Magic Weapons** trait:

> The slaad's weapon attacks are magical.

And they have a **Multiattack** action:

> The slaad makes three attacks: one with its bite and two with its claws or greatsword.

Are the **Bite** and/or **Claws** attacks magical? Are they considered to be weapon attacks?

Comment: Tangentially related: [Is an Unarmed Strike considered a Weapon attack?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/58158/is-an-unarmed-strike-considered-a-weapon-attack)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

#### Yes, its Bite and Claw attacks are magical weapon attacks.

Usually a monster's claws, bites, and other attack actions are listed as weapon attacks.  In the stat blocks for Death Slaad and Gray Slaad, these actions are written as:

> ***Bite (Slaad Form Only)***. Melee Weapon Attack...
>
> ***Claws (Slaad Form Only)***. Melee Weapon Attack...

Since the bite and claws are weapon attacks, they therefore benefit from the Magic Weapons feature.

> ***Magic Weapons.*** The slaad’s weapon attacks are magical.